# Is it safe to validate a Google Plus Oauth 2 access token sent from client to authenticate a user on server?

Tags: php, ios, authentication, google-plus

I would like to use **Google Plus Sign-In** to authenticate my users in an iOS app. I have followed the guide for iOS described on https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in. The sign in on *client side* works perfectly with the Google + Platform. I have not understood how to authenticate the user on *server side*.

I have seen that the access token on the client can be validated to some extent on https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=XYZ123. Is it safe to authentice a client by validating the access token that the user sent over HTTPS?

Are there better solutions when using the Google+ Sign-In button on the client? As I understand it, Google recommends using the Google+ Sign-In button:

> The Google+ Sign-In button is an easy way for users to sign up and sign in to your app. This allows you to know who they are on Google+ and to build a more personalized experience for your app, all without having to create yet another username and password

Comment: Good question, I am also interested in this, since I will include Google Plus login in my iOS app in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes. On iOS that's the best method of going about it right now. The important thing is that your verification checks what you want, generally:

- The client ID is a client ID from your project.
- You only use the user ID from the access token
- The token isn't expired

The expiry, and other basic verification, is handled automatically when you called tokeninfo. Just make sure you check the client ID, and use the user ID from the the tokeninfo response to look up the local user.

```
{
 "issued_to": "1234.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "1234.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "104824858261236811362",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
 "expires_in": 3584,
 "access_type": "online"
}
```

This is an example of the response. The client ID is the "audience" field here (actually, also issued to), and the user_id is the Google user ID - that's what you should look up in your database to find the matching application user.

On Android and the web there are two other options: retrieve an ID token (basically a cryptographically signed token that directly contains similar information to what you get back from calling tokeninfo with the access token), and retrieving a code (that can be used to exchange for an access token and id token on the server side). Those two aren't currently available on iOS, so passing the access token via HTTPS is the best option currently.